# What do planeswalkers earn on level ups?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

Each level up, a planeswalker unlocks something new. It's often 4hp, additional mana per color match, or a leveled up ability.

Here's what I have so far, **tested only with Chandra**:

- 2: 1st ability is now lvl 1
- 6: 2nd ability is now lvl 2
- 14: 2nd ability is now lvl 1
- 26: 3rd ability is now lvl 1
- 31: +4hp
- 32: 3rd ability is now lvl 2
- 33: Your planeswalker regeneration improved
- 34: Your planeswalker regeneration improved
- 35: Your planeswalker regeneration improved
- 36: +4hp
- 37: Your planeswalker regeneration improved

Is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

Comment: I'd really love to see this as well! It seems all planeswalkers get their second ability at level 14 and their third one at 26. But the other rewards seem to vary between 'walkers. Level 17 is good (more mana per match) for some walkers but boring for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information is not quite complete, but there is a [crowd-sourced spreadsheet linked on the *D3 Go!* forums](https://d3go.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=36449#p454062). There's a little too much information to list everything here (49 levels * 5 planeswalkers) not to mention any future planeswalkers that may be released.

However, the ability unlocks are fairly consistent across all 5 planeswalkers:

- **2**: 1st ability, lvl 1
- **8**: 1st ability, lvl 2
- **14**: 2nd ability, lvl 1
- **20**: 2nd ability, lvl 2
- **26/27**: 3rd ability, lvl 1
- **32/33**: 3rd ability, lvl 2
- **38**: 1st ability, lvl 3
- **44/45**: 2nd ability, lvl 3
- **50**: 3rd ability, lvl 3